# GITHUB ERROR: Permission to user2/repository-name.git denied to user1

Tags: git, github

Stuck with this issue for the past few hours and cant find a solution. So here we go. Apologies for the long question.

I have two Github accounts on my `Macbook`

1. Personal account with username - user1
2. A company account with username - user2

I was using the personal account mostly and am now trying to push to the company account on this laptop.

While pushing I get the error

```
ERROR: Permission to user2/repository-name.git denied to user1.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.


Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It is a completely new repository that I am trying to push to, following the instructions that Github provides for new repositories.

I checked

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

Both are related to user2.

```
git config credential.helper
```

returns `osxkeychain`. I deleted the github related access from there. Now if I run the below command from the terminal, it just hangs and does nothing.

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase https://github.com
```

Running this command also returns the correct details

```
git remote get-url --all origin
```

Response is

```
git@github.com:user2/repository-name.git
```

I also deleted and re-added my `ssh` keys to the company github account.

I am out of sorts here, not knowing what to try further. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***So that it may help someone in the future***

My issue was that I had the same key still added to my old account. Using that key, it was still trying to use my old account in the new repository.
That is why it was saying that the old user did not have access to the new repository.

If you need to use both accounts, here is an article on how to [Handle multiple Github accounts on MacOS](https://gist.github.com/Jonalogy/54091c98946cfe4f8cdab2bea79430f9).

Answer (score 0):

> `git@github.com`

This is an SSH URL, which means the `credential.helper` is *not* used at all, considering it caches credentials (username/token) for HTTPS connection.

If you want to make sure to use `user2`'s credentials, you can:

- get or create `user2` [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)
- switch to HTTPS with:
  `git remote set-url origin https://user2@github.com/users/reponsitory-name.git`
- Enter the PAT when prompted by the credential helper.